# Can Gnuplot take different arguments at run time? maybe with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, gnuplot

I have 500 files to plot and I want to do this automatically. I have the gnuplot script
that does the plotting with the file name hard coded. I would like to have a loop that calls gnuplot every iteration with a different file name, but it does not seem that gnuplot support command line arguments.

Is there an easy way? I also installed the gnuplot-python package in case I can do it via a python script.However, I couldn't find the api so it's a bit difficult to figure out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can transform your gnuplot script to a shell script by prepending the lines

```
#!/bin/sh
gnuplot << EOF
```

appending the line

```
EOF
```

and substituting every `$` by `\$`.  Then, you can substitute every occurence of the filename by `$1` and call the shell script with the filename as parameter.

Comment: Works like a charm... thanks! 
I added another script that loops and call this gnuplot one with a different file each time and that's it.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the $'s in Sven Marnach's solution (the lines between EOF are called a "here script" in shell parlance): in my experience, one uses shell variables as usual, but $s that are meant for gnuplot itself must be escaped.

Here is an example:

```
for distrib in "uniform" "correlated" "clustered"
do
    gnuplot << EOF
    # gnuplot preamble omitted for brevity

    set output "../plots/$distrib-$eps-$points.pdf"
    set title "$distrib distribution, eps = $eps, #points = $points"

    plot "../plots/dat/$distrib-$eps-$points.dat" using 1:(\$2/$points) title "exact NN"
EOF

done
```

Note the backslash escaping the dollar so that gnuplot sees it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to generate 500 gnuplot scripts like so:

```
for filename in list_of_files:
    outfile = open(filename + '-script', 'w')
    outfile.write(script_text % (filename,))
```

where `script_text` is the text of your gnuplot script with the filename replaced with a `%s`.

Comment: So your solution is to generate the 500 scripts automatically and then write a script that calls gnuplot 500 times. Not the most elegant solution but this will work. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, elegance is for people who know what they're doing. I know very little about gnuplot despite having written http://www.nmichaels.org/graph/graphinator.py

Answer (score 1):

I've done this some times. But don't use EOF, because you cannot write on bash inside the << EOF and EOF tags. Depending on the names of the files you can do it in diferent ways.

a) If the filenames are loopable (sort of 1.dat 2.dat 3.dat, etc.)

```
#!/bin/bash    
for((i=0;i<1;i++)) do
  echo "plot '-' u 1:2"
  for((j=1;j<=3;j++)) do
     cat $i.dat
     echo "e"
  done
done | gnuplot -persist
```

The first loop is a kind of buffer to feed it all to gnuplot.

b) If the filenames aren't loopable (such as ñlasjkd.dat ajñljd.mov añlsjkd.gif) you first need to move them to a new folder. Then do

```
#!/bin/bash    

ffiles=$(ls | xargs)       # a list of the folder's files
# Use the list to pipe all the data to gnuplot using cat
for((i=0;i<1;i++)) do
  echo "plot '-' u 1:2 w lp"; 
  cat $ffiles; 
  echo "e"; 
done | gnuplot -persist
```

c) If you want some more, that is: to keep the information of the separated files just on one file... but maintaning the datasheets alive use "index" of gnuplot (if gnuplot reads two black lines guesses that is another datasheet)

```
#!/bin/bash

ffiles=$(ls|xargs)
ls $ffiles > ffiles.list # A file with the folder's files
while read line 
do
    cat $line; 
    echo -e; echo -e;
done < ffiles.list > alldata.dat 
# ^-feeding ffiles.list to the while loop 
# and writing the file alldata.dat
```

now you can go to gnuplot and acces to one datasheet

```
plot 'alldata.dat' index 1 u 1:2
```

and you will see the first file appearing on the list "ffiles.list". If you whant to see more than one, say 4

```
plot 'alldata.dat' index 1:4 u 1:2
```

tricky but easy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, there's an easier way.

In the gnuplot script, replace all occurrences of your filename with `$0`.
Then in bash, loop over your plot files (let's say they are .txt files in $plotsDir) and call gnuplot:

```
for f in "$plotsDir/*.txt"; do
    echo "call '$f'" | gnuplot
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this.  Your gnuplot input file, say `plot.gp`, contains a line

```
plot "data"
```

or something like that.  Save the lines before this line in `plot1.gp` and the lines after this line in `plot2.gp`.  Now call gnuplot as

```
gnuplot plot1.gp -e `plot "data"` plot2.gp
```

which facilitates passing the name of `data` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, it works but one minor problem. I have in the gnuplot script lines that use the file name such as: set output 'data.png'. I need to replace it with the command line argument as well.

Comment: Of course you could split the script into even more files, but maybe have a look at my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I create a file named `test.txt` containing `plot [0:20] x;`

I run `gnuplot test.txt` and I see that gnuplot has indeed read contents of my file, so it does support arguments at runtime.

Comment: That's true. It takes the gnuplot script and runs it. However, my question is about taking arguments to be used in the gnuplot script. I might not explained it very well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Different methods of solving this problem are also covered in [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot) :

- Using `-e`
- Using `-c` or `call` with `ARG0` like variables (gnuplot >= 5)
- Using `call` with `$0` like variables  (gnuplot <= 4.6.6)
- Using environment variables and `system()`
- Piping the program into gnuplot