# How to give command line arguments to gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am writing a script to plot multiple files from multiple files one at a time. I also want to save the output of each plot corresponding to the data file. How can we give both arguments to GNUPlot. For example: sample GNUPlot script

```
set xlabel "a"
set ylabel "b"
set zlabel "c"
set term postscript
set output "??"    #'??' implies variable i.e. take file name from commandline
splot "??" with points,"??" with points    #'??' implies variable i.e. take file name from commandline
```

and this script will be run by another shell script generating the required file names.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the `-e` command-line option of gnuplot. See this question for an example: [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot)

Comment: Did you find any official documentartion for the `-e` option? I'm searching for hours, still whithout luck.

Comment: @Wolf You find it in the gnuplot docs the  section "batch/interactive operation".

Comment: @Christoph thanks, but it's still a little confusing: I found two versions of the same version's docs, [Batch/Interactive Operation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node46.html) and [Batch/Interactive_Operation - Gnuplot: An Interactive Plotting Program](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/gnuplot-doc/htmldocs/Batch_002fInteractive_005fOperation.html). It is so fundamental that I cannot believe why this information is hidden like this.

Comment: @Wolf I agree that the info. should be easier to find. Luckily we have stackoverflow! As for the different documentations, they correspond to different gnuplot versions.

Answer (score -2):

Try this simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

file="output.png"
infile1="$1"
infile2="$2"

echo "
set xlabel \"a\"
set ylabel \"b\"
set zlabel \"c\"
set term postscript
set output \"$file\"    #'??' implies variable i.e. take file name from commandline
splot \"$infile1\" with points,\"$infile2\" with points    #'??' implies variable i.e. take file name from commandline
" > sample.gp && gnuplot sample.gp
```

And call it like `./script data.txt data2.txt`
You will have the output stored in `output.png` and the gnuplot file stored in `sample.gp` file.

It's easy to add more files to plot, even if the number of plotted files is different everytime. You can then also store your .gp file in different output.

Comment: That's horrific. Please don't do this. Use -e