# how to call gnuplot in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, 3d, gnuplot, dynamically-generated

I have to create program can plot 3D graph from text file.
Now, I can write the code for plot 3D graph.
but i have no idea to call gnuplot in vb.net.
My program is written on window apps.
So, i try to search code in the Internet.

and i find this:

http://classes.bus.oregonstate.edu/ba371/lu/VBlabs/VBgnuplot.html

I have already tried this code by console but it doesn't work.
Although, It can work. I cannot resolve it to use with window apps.
because I'm new in vb.net.

I have to write this program finish within 1 week.
Anyone can help me? pls.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It Sounds like you are trying to pass a file generated by your vb application to gnuplot, is that correct?

Comment: yes, can i do like that? can u guide me for do it? @jcwrequests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vb we can use the Shell Function. I am basing this on the below link. My escape sequence for the quotes may need to be adjusted but this should work. I have also included a link to the shell function which also has a code example using Process a well.

```
SHELL("gnuplot -e """filename='foo.data'""" foo.plg")
```

[How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx

Good luck.

Comment: i have something to ask u. how can i adapt code in this link http://classes.bus.oregonstate.edu/ba371/lu/VBlabs/VBgnuplot.html to use with window form

Comment: Can u guild line me for the next step? i cannot do it. I have already had a text file which is the Gnuplot's code for plotting 3D graph. From this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx I can call the Gnuplot but i dont want to do like this. I want the Gnuplot autometic plot graph from the file text. Then, show the graph on window from. Can u give me an example code. I cannot find its and I'm not proficient in programming for write this code by myself. i'm waiting for ur kind.