# Can i call gnuplot from vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, graph, 3d, gnuplot

I try to find the way to call gnuplot from vb.net but I'm still cannot solve it. Or Gnuplot does not support in vb.net ? I want the Gnuplot autometic plot graph from the file text. Then, show the graph on window from (vb). Can u give me an example code. I cannot find its and I'm not proficient in programming for write this code by myself.

please, someone confirm that i can call Gnuplot in vb.net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you ask the very same question a second time? [how to call gnuplot in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19472473/2604213).

Comment: @Christoph I'm so sorry because my professor advice me to write new program. He said that c++ is better.

Comment: So why do you ask again about VB?

Comment: @Christoph because i'm not sure that can call it from vb. I'm so sorry. i will delete this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call Gnuplot, just like any other Programm with ex. [Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)