# create a figure file by gnuplot

Tags: linux, shell, gnuplot, figure

I made a script as following to plot with GnuPlot.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
#file: myplot
set term svg;
set out 'figfile.svg';
plot './datafile.dat' with lp;
set term wxt 0;
set out;
```

So, I can create a figure file as

```
$./myplot
```

However, I have to edit the script to replace 'figfile.svg' and 'datafile.dat' manually. Can I modify this script and use the following format to create a figure file?

```
$./myplot datafile.dat figfile.svg
```

Thanks all.

Comment: For other options see [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your call to `gnuplot` with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

gnuplot <<EOF
set term svg
set out '$1'
plot '$2' with lp
set term wxt 0
set out
EOF
```

The shell would substitute `$1` and `$2` in the script with the first and second command line parameters.

Comment: Note also that `gnuplot` does not require semicolon-terminated lines.