# gnuplot - can I put all the settings for a plot in a file, and call it before the plot command?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to save the set commands used to define my graph.

Basically I would like to save the style of the line, the color, output name, ranges and so on; in a file

Then I would like to call it from a script, like

```
gnuplot <setting script name> <data file> "plot <plot commands>"
```

Is this possible? The manual don't mention any kind of capability to load the options that you set for the plot function, from an external file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches.

You can store very general settings in a `~/.gnuplot` file.

Otherwise, you can make a script, named `myplot`, which constructs it locally

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot << EOF
<all settings>
plot "$1"
EOF
```

Which you call by `./myplot <datafile>`

Comment: Thanks Bernhard, Sorry, I didn't realize that I can append the rest of the options after the $1 :) Is almost 3 AM and my brain is starting to leave me behind

Answer (score 0):

You can, e.g. put all settings in one file e.g. `settings.gp`

```
set terminal ...
set xtics ...
```

Have one file `plot.gp` which contains all plotting commands which use a variable `datafile`:

```
plot datafile using 1:2
```

The variable `datafile` can be given using the `-e` option, and the settings file can be loaded with `load`

```
gnuplot -e "datafile='mydatafile.dat'; load 'settings.gp'" plot.gp
```

See also [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213)

Comment: Much appreciated Christoph; it is a good variation on the method that Bernhard posted. Altho it requires basically 3 files: one with the settings, the datafile and the script that launch the whole thing; while in the other solution, you have only the script and data file, so it fits perfectly my case. Thanks!

Comment: That was the way how I plotted all the graphs of my thesis: One main file with general settings, a plotting file, which could be changed with a few variables given by the `-e` parameter to produce several, similar plots.