# How to define a gnuplot output file as a variable?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

In my bash file I have this declaration:

```
gnuplot -e "filename='Traffic1'" MyplotFile
```

Now I want to pass the **Traffic1** or better to say the value of filename to the name of my gnuplot  output file, which is in png format.

I have these line on MyplotFile:

```
set output 'filename.png'
```

But the output is **filename.png** ! I want to have **Traffic1.png** as my output. How do I define this line correctly:

```
set output 'filename.png'
```

P.S. If you need to know about **-e** please go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `'filename.png'` you have simply defined a string. How should gnuplot know, that you mean a variable?

You can either concatenate your variable with the extension string

```
set output filename . '.png'
```

or you can use `sprintf`:

```
set output sprintf('%s.png', filename)
```