# how to pass variable to -e on gnuplot?

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I want to define gnuplot output which is a png file.how to define **fileName** on gnuplot.

```
    #This lines and also Traffic$j are define on my bash file.
    # Traffic$j is the name of file and that is valid. Traffic$j is on the loop
    # j is loop index
.
.

    fileName=Traffic$j
.
.
```

I try this:

```
gnuplot -e "filename=${!fileName}" plotFile
```

But I go this error:

> line 0: constant expression required

I try ruakh's idea:

```
gnuplot -e "filename = '${!fileName}'" plotFile
```

But I gut this warning:

> "plotFile", line 12: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

line 12? look at my last line of the script.

How can I pass a variable to **-e** switch on gnuplot?

**Update:**
**My plotFile is this:**

```
set terminal png size 720,450 enhanced font "H,11"
set output filename . '.png'

plot '../_numXY' using 2:3:(sprintf('%d', $1)) with labels offset 0,1 point pointtype 7 ps 2 lc rgb "green" notitle, \
filename using 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) with vectors linewidth 6 lc rgb "blue" notitle #line 12
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not so much how to pass a variable, as how to quote a string. If, for example, `$j` is `3` and `$Traffic3` is `file.txt`, then what you're passing to `-e` is `filename=file.txt`, when what you need to pass is something like `filename = "file.txt"` or `filename = 'file.txt'`. So:

```
gnuplot -e "filename = '${!fileName}'" plotFile
```

---

**Edited to add:** In a comment, you write:

> thanks, $Traffic3 is not file.txt. or better to say I do not have $Traffic3 but I have Traffic3. Traffic3 is not parameter. It is the name of of file itself and not refer to another thing like file.txt

This means that you should not be writing `${!fileName}`, but rather `$fileName`. The notation `${!fileName}` means roughly, "O.K., so the value of `$fileName` is the name of another variable. Give me the value of that variable." So you just want:

```
gnuplot -e "filename = '$fileName'" plotFile
```

Comment: thanks, $Traffic3 is not file.txt. or better to say I do not have $Traffic3 but I have Traffic3. Traffic3 is not parameter. It is the name of of file itself and not refer to another thing like file.txt

Comment: @alex: In that case, you should not be writing `${!fileName}` (which means "the value of the variable whose name is the value of `$fileName` -- for example, if `$fileName` is `Traffic3`, then `${!fileName}` means `$Traffic3`), but rather `$fileName`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't want to cast indirect variable expansion?

```
gnuplot -e "filename=${fileName}" plotFile
```

Comment: thanks for help. But it tell me:  line 0: undefined variable: Traffic1

Comment: Because that should be `gnuplot -e "filename='${fileName}'" plotFile`. Please see [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328603/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-gnuplot).

Comment: @Christoph thanks you christoph. god bless you you make my day. thanks.