# gnuplot command line arguments and call arguments

Tags: gnuplot, command-line-interface, interactive

following up from [the question on SO about command line parameters to gnuplot scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330483/3337196), and its corresponding answer, I see that I can make a script myscript.gp like

```
if(!exist("parameters")) parameters=""
plot "< myprog ".parameters u 1:2
```

and call it with

```
$ gnuplot -e "parameters='-m 5'" myscript.gp
```

However, I could achieve a similar result when running in interactive mode with myscript2.gp as

```
parameters="$0"
plot "< myprog ".parameters u 1:2
```

and calling it from the interactive prompt as

```
gnuplot> call "myscript2.gp" "-m 5"
```

And now the question. As I see it those two methods are not connected and the $O would fail when when running in batch, whereas the 'parameters' is not updated when using call.

How do I set a script which could be called from the shell command line *AS WELL AS* from the gnuplot interactive command line? Another way to ask it, is it possible to test in which conditions was the script called?

Thanks,

Comment: Regarding the same question you refer, have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31815067/2174266)?

Comment: @vagoberto, No I didn't, it wasn't there last time I checked. Plus, I was using the standard version of gnuplot. But it looks like they improved it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around, I found a *quite* inelegant solution, but that could help to achieve what I want.

```
parameters=""                                  # sets default value
if ("$#" eq sprintf("%d",1)) parameters="$0"   # if using call with 1 parameter: $#=1
if (exist("bpar")) parameters=bpar             # checking for batch call

plot "< myprog ".parameters u 1:2
```

which can then be called by either

```
$ gnuplot -e "bpar='-m 5'" myscript.gp
```

or

```
gnuplot> call "myscript2.gp" "-m 5"
```

Comment: Please note that this only work when the interactive call is made with one and only one argument. It should probably be included in a loop (but a basic do for [] {} complained about 'Old style if') or the different values ORed together. But I have no time now to look further.