# Pass data to gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=42
./test.gp
```

And this is the gnuplot script (`test.gp`):

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set grid
set title "This is the title (`echo $foo`)"

set terminal png large
set output "/tmp/test.png"
set samples 50, 50
plot [-10:10] sin(x)
```

I'm led to believe that this should display the title as **`This is the title (42)`**. But it doesn't.
The resulting image looks like this:
[image: Resulting plot]
Also I want to

```
plot [-10:10] sin(x + `echo $foo`)
```

But that results in an error:

```
plot [-10:10] sin(x+)
                    ^
"./test.gp", line 9: invalid expression
```

I use gnuplot 4.6.

EDIT: moved solution to separate answer as requested in the comments.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213 for several possibilities.

Comment: Have you tried putting `export foo=42` in your bash script? Also `foo=42 ./test.gp` works fine. And the solution given in the edited question is also given in the duplicate.

Comment: @Christoph Mmm. Probably missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Marking your edit as "Added solution" to a question seems to be not a proper way to close the question as it was reopened by 5 respected men.
Move your "EDIT" to an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213) but they did not appear to work for me. (Although I've been advised the solution provided below is actually mentioned there aswell).

I found that changing the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash


foo=42
gnuplot -e "foo='${foo}'" ./test.gp
```

works better. Also the GNUPLOT script becomes more readable:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set grid
set title "This is the title (".foo.")"

set terminal png large
set output "/tmp/test.png"
set samples 50, 50
plot [-10:10] sin(x + foo)
```