# gnuplot plot running through windows cmd

Tags: windows, shell, gnuplot

I have gnuplot on Windows. I want to write the script on windows shell to authomatically plot in gnuplot, namely something like

```
   "...\gnuplot.exe" 'plot "file:exe" using 1:2'
```

But when trying to run such script, an error occurs: it writes "'plot", line 0: Cannot open script file 'plot'".

I tried to create temporary script a.cmd, in which the command

```
   plot "file:exe" using 1:2
```

is present. Now my command to run gnuplot looks like

```
   "...\gnuplot.exe" "a.cmd"
```

But then nothing happened, gnuplot isn't running with no errors.

I know that to load script in gnuplot window I need to run

```
   load "a.cmd" ,
```

and all will work. But when I try to launch

```
  ".../gnuplot.exe" 'load "a.cmd"' ,
```

then again error "Cannot open script file 'load'" occurs.

Next, I try to put a.cmd to gnuplot folder, and then run

```
 ".../gnuplot.exe" a.cmd
```

Now it launches without errors, but the gnuplot screen appears on the second and vanishes.

So how to run gnuplot plot through cmd script (launching the script -> launching gnuplot with plotting)?

Comment: Windows is really useless with single quotes. I have never tried it, but I suspect if you put all your *gnuplot* commands in a file called `plot.cmd` and run `gnuplot < plot.cmd` it will probably work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213