# Drag and drop script for gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data I would like to plot in gnuplot. For being able to plot them I wrote a script called "plot_A.gp". In it I set the axis values, labels and the output terminal.
In order not to have it modificated for every data file, I was wondering if it is possible to make the script able to handle drag and drop-files.

As example script:

```
set xrange [0 to 100]
set xlabel "x-axis"
set ylabel "y-axis"
set terminal eps
set output %1.pdf
plot %1 using 1:($2*$2) with lines
```

How can I set `%1` to the file name I just dropped onto the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please execute the script with `call` instead of `load` at the gnuplot prompt. `call` accepts upto 10 arguments. Before gnuplot 5.0, these arguments are called $0, $1, ..., $9.

In gnuplot 4.6, your script would look like this:

```
datafile="$0"
outputfile="$0".".pdf"
set xrange [0 to 100]
set xlabel "x-axis"
set ylabel "y-axis"
plot "hello" using 1:($$2*$$2) with lines
set terminal eps
set output outputfile
replot
set terminal wxt
set output
```

Because `$2` refers to the third parameter to the script, to access the second column use `$$2` instead. Alternately, you can also use `1:(column(2)*column(2))`.

You would call it like this.

```
gnuplot> call "plot_A.gp" "hello"
```

This will plot the data in the file "hello" and create a pdf called "hello.pdf". I have also reset the terminal back to `wxt`, as a best-practice.

From gnuplot 5.0, using $0, $1 etc is deprecated. Instead you should use the special variables ARG0, ARG2, ..., ARG9. I don't have access to gnuplot 5.0. But I think you just need to use `ARG0` instead of `$0`. Please you could refer to this answer to [How to pass command line argument to gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815067/5470810)